# Deletar item do listview no Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Como faço para deletar um item do meu listview ? Eu deleto o item, porém quando clico no item seguinte é selecionado o mesmo item que eu havia deletado.

Meu código:

```
adapter.Remove("LISTA 1");
adapter.Remove("LISTA 2");
adapter.Remove("LISTA 3");
adapter.Remove("LISTA 4");
```

Comment: do you using ObservableCollection in your itemsource? Só pra constar, esse é StackOverFlow em português, caso você seja brasileiro, aqui pode postar a pergunta em Pt msm.

Comment: Eu não estou usando !

Comment: Por favor Renato, traduza sua pergunta ou ela será fechada pela comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, creio que possa tentar algum dos pontos que vou listar abaixo:

- Verifique se seu adapter possui uma sobrecarga para utilizar uma ObservableCollection no lugar do List, já que o observablecollection vai notificar quando algo for alterado.
- Você pode fazer o set do seu adapter novamente após remover o item da sua lista, dessa forma carrega um lista já sem o item que foi removido
- Você pode verificar o funcionamento do NotifyDataSetChanged do seu Adapter, seria o mesmo funcionamento do ObservableCollection que listei primeiro.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica BrianSouza, fazendo set do adapter novamente funcionou muito bem, queria aproveitar a oportunidade te pergunta sabe como que faz para mudar um item da listview de cor ?

Comment: Opa, valeu. Marca como resposta pois sua dúvida pode ser a mesma de outros. Não esqueça de editar seu post para deixar no moldes do Stack. Sobre a sua dúvida, abra outro post para podermos separar os tópicos.